# How to use whereRaw in jenssegers/laravel-mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I'm using [Laravel-MongoDB from jenssegers](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb).
Now I wish to create a custom query.
By documentation, I need to use the RAW method.

```
$model = User::whereRaw(['$limit : 5'])->get();
dd($model);
```

Why my result is empty?

```
Collection {#235 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

Comment: I'd start installing the laravel-debug bar and looking at the queries performed.

Comment: the docs seem to say you can use the regular builder methods like  take() and skip()

Comment: @lolalola, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Rubens Mariuzzo>Laravel Framework version 5.1.19 (LTS), MongoDB vewrsion 3.0.6

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [Moloquent's `whereRaw`](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#raw-expressions) method expect a complete PHP array instead of passing a string of JSON object inside a PHP array.

```php
$model = User::whereRaw(['$limit' => '5'])->get();
```

Give it a try, and let me know if it helps.

## Update

The docs also list that the following is possible:

```php
$model = User::take(5)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, but i try this and get the same result (empty item list)

Comment: I need create native MongoDB query, doesn't use jenssegers query builder.

Comment: But, using Moloquent#take method, will not translate to native MongoDB query? Have you checked the generated query? Try: `dd(User::take(5)->toSql())` and see what you get.